# wildcard for number in MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, numbers

I have following rows in my database table,

```
number:

1
2
3
4
100
101
102
103
104
200
201
202
```

I want to get output of all 100's like[100,101,102,103,104], but i have tried following codes,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number RLIKE '[[:<:]]1';
```

it shows [1,100,101,102,103,104]

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number LIKE '1%';
```

it shows [1,100,101,102,103,104], i only want get number from 100 to 104, i don't want number 1.

Comment: why don't you just say `where number>=100 and number<=104`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i want output all 100's

Comment: @begamfouzia Have you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use between clause like following which select range.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number BETWEEN 100 AND 199;
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE number LIKE "1%"
  AND length(number)=3;
```

<kbd>**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2afe4/2)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

to get all numbers between 100 and 199 you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number BETWEEN 100 AND 199;
```